# Add new CSS style from an external file and different class

Tags: php, css, class, import, external

I have a page called index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css" />
...
<body>
<div class="my_class"></div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

In `mystyle.css` there is no declaration for `.my_class`
I have another file called external_style.css where there is no declaration for `.my_class` either but there is a class called `.new_class`

Can not import or append external_style.css - cause it will overwrite other elements.

My question is:
How can I get the properties of .new_class from external_style.css into `.my_class` without importing the file.
Is there a way to read that file using php?
Is there another better solution?

Comment: Why don't you open the file locally or look at it in a browser with developer tools and copy .new_class from external_style.css and move it to mystyle.css?

Comment: You likely have this problem because you're not following the best practices for HTML/CSS.

Comment: What do you mean by: there is no declaration for .my_class either but there is a class called .new_class

Comment: Is there a reason you would not add `.new_class` to the mystyle.css

Comment: you can load as many style sheets as you want. but if you have class/id definitions in multiple sheets, then the "later" sheets will override the earlier ones.

Comment: Well, the entire thing is on a running platform and is dynamic styled by users. I need to apply different properties from every user - that external_style.css contains allways the declaration of .new_class styled by each of them.

Comment: So is the `external_style.css` generated dynamically where are you getting the information for `.new_class` being stored?

Comment: in `/path_to_user_account/external_style.css`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `.my_class` doesn't exist within **mystyles.css** can you not just take your code from `.new_class` within **external_style.css** and create a `.my_class` in **mystyles.css**? or have i missed the point?

Comment: Well, even if I create .my_class in mystyle.css I will not be able to load the properties from external_style.css each time. 
The entire thing is on a running platform with multiple users.
Every user is creating his own style for .new_class.
All I want is to get .new_class properties into .my_class when I'm opening each account.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using a PHP file with a CSS header. This article should get you started: http://sperling.com/examples/pcss/

Answer (score 0):

**There are a couple things you can do to achieve what you are trying to accomplish**

1. **Move custom layout data to database:**  Rather than creating custom files for each user store the users custom css information in a database record for the user.

   You could easily identify the user and use javascript to update the CSS.
2. **More scalabe style sheets:**  If importing the the external_style.css is affecting the global layout you should revisit the way you are identifying elements on the page so that does not happen.  Then you could simply import the users custom style sheet.
   Try using IDs in addition to Classes as well as wrapping sections of content in Divs.  Use those identifiers to make sure importing external_style.css does not overwrite everything.